# How can I join 2 tables even if some occurences are NULL MySQL (Left-join)

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I currently have 2 tables, *projects* and *data*. *Projects* contains the list of all my projects and *data* contains information about what was done on the project, each day a row is added for each project on the *data* table.

A project can be created later on.

What I need to do is to get, on a specific day, all the data about all the projects and if a project was not created at the time, I need to know it and have *NULL* values for the data columns.

Here is what I tried :

```
SELECT project_key FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM data d WHERE CAST(d.date_added as DATE) = '2022-11-08') as d
ON p.project_key = d.project_key
```

From what I understand, since I am doing a *LEFT JOIN* and since the subrequest is executed at first, my result should include the project that was not created at the time.

Here is a sample of the structure of my tables and what I want to have as a result :

***projects***

```
project_key     name
EV              Easier
CAN             Canva
```

***data***

```
id              time_spent      project_key         date_added
1               1000            EV                  2022-11-07
2               600             EV                  2022-11-08
3               1900            Canva               2022-11-09
4               2030            EV                  2022-11-09
```

***expected result*** (for date_added = 2022-11-07)

```
project_key     time_spent
EV              1000
Canva           NULL
```

Comment: "Left outer join" allows you to see the rows of all projects, that did not get a matching data value.
Because their data will be null

Comment: It seems you need a "full join". Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: If you want the reverse of my first comment, simply convert to right outer join...
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @MortenBork I also tried with 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' and I get the same result. When I count the number of rows I get a different value if I change the date.

Comment: I provided you with an answer, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @TheImpaler I added the structure of my tables as well as an expected result

Comment: @HectoB Left join from projects to Subquery on data is the correct approach. Do you have additional where clause criteria you're not showing us following the join?  is the query you have listed doing what you expect to do?  if not what are it's results?  if so; what's the problem? I would expect what you have listed to work, unless you have a where clause or having on "D" table in which case the left join is being negated and treated like an inner join

Comment: If a project does not have any task on the day, do you still need to show that project?

Comment: What you have works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/phYE4dku `SELECT p. project_key, time_spent
  FROM projects p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM data d WHERE CAST(d.date_added as DATE) = '2022-11-08') as d
    ON p.project_key = d.project_key`

Comment: Why is your expected results 1000 shouldn't it be 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question right:

You want to see all data rows on a given date?

```
SELECT p.project_key, d.project_key FROM projects p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM data d WHERE CAST(d.date_added as DATE) = '2022-11-08') as d
ON p.project_key = d.project_key
```

This should show you the "optional" project key from the projects table in the first column, and the "required" project key from the data table in the second column

If this give you the opposite of your expected data set, just try to switch back to a Left outer join, should fix it :)
And then I apologies for misunderstanding you

Comment: I don't know what happened, this now is working for me, I even tried doing it again with only a "LEFT JOIN" and I get my expected result. I don't really know why but I thank you for your help !

Comment: In the first example you gave, you only see the "project key" from the "projects" table.
You will just see nulls, when there is no projects that aligns with data.
That is likely what confused you? don't you think?

Comment: @HectoB  This is odd.  I'd expect the left join from projects to data to be correct.  unless you have the order of your tables changed...

Comment: @xQbert I think it was always working, and think what confused me, was that I didn't notice he was only outputting the project table, so I assumed he was simply joining from the wrong table. 

But after I noticed, and he started displaying both tables data fields- he says it works. I am 99% sure, he just overlooked that he was only seeing the rows of one table...

Comment: @MortenBork  makes sense.  I couldn't see how your initial query woudn't work.  Though expected results are wrong for date queried.

Comment: Basically to troubleshoot I was only displaying a COUNT(*) of my result, and I wanted that number to be the same for evry date I could possibily try. I obviously made an error somewhere and did not check properly the result of some of my requests.